# Does "I'm staying in Dallas through April" mean until April 1 or until April 30?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

So, this is embarrassing ... I'm a native English speaker, and someone told me they're "staying in Dallas through April." Does that mean they're leaving Dallas April 1 or April 30? This [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127102/meaning-of-through) addressed the question, but it only got one answer, and I'm trying to figure out if there are multiple interpretations to this. Thanks!

Comment: Since '1 through 10' includes 10, I would assume April 30 is included. But I've always found it a weird phrase.

Comment: This phrase lacks precision, so it doesn't really tell you when he is leaving.  I would guess that he would most likely be in Dallas through at least part of April, but not necessarily all the way until the 30th.

Answer (score 1):

I would say up to April 30. The month mentioned is included. Merriam-Webster is an authoritative dictionary of US English, and they give this as one of the meanings of *through*:

> 4—used as a function word to indicate a period of time:
> such as [...]
> c: to **and including**
> *Monday through Friday*

[Through (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through)

Lexico (Oxford Dictionaries) gives the same 'including' meaning:

> 5 North American
> Up to **and including** (a particular point in an ordered
> sequence)
> *they will be in London from March 24 through May 7*

[Through (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/through)